# How to enable TLS 1.2 on IIS7 on a shared server?

Tags: ssl, iis-7

I've got a hosting on an IIS7 Server at NetworkSolutions.

I dont' have access to the Registry.

Can I enable TLS1.2 on this server via the IIS7 desktop client (remove IIS7)?

Comment: That's what you should talk to the hosting provider.

Answer (score 1):

No, TLS and the Crypto-Stack in Windows is a feature of the OS, not of IIS, you can not change it through any IIS tools.

Talk to your hosting provider.